# The modification target of 忌み嫌われる

Tags: relative-clauses

The sentence is taken from a fantasy visual novel.

> 現の神と古の神が相克するこの世界でも類を見ない、 双方にとって、 忌み嫌われる世界の敵

It's a bit unclear for me which clause is modified by the word 「忌み嫌われる」
Does it mean: "The abhorred/detested **enemy** of the word" or "The abhorred/detested **world's** enemy"?

**Edit 1**: Full sentence provided

Comment: I guess I should have written the full sentence from the start

Comment: Are you sure that the sentence ends there? If so, what sentences comes before and after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

忌み嫌われる modifies (世界の)敵. The first half of the sentence says 現の神 and 古の神 conflict with each other in 'this world', and this "世界の敵" is detested by both 現の神 and 古の神. Interpreting this part as "detested world" is grammatically possible, but it doesn't match the context.